# subscription.subscribe and unsubscribe is not a function

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm trying to unsubscribe to an Observable and I'm seeing the following error:

```
[ts] Property 'unsubscribe' does not exist on type 'Observable<number>'. Did you mean 'subscribe'?
```

This error is related to code: `this.subscription.unsubscribe();`

**Here's the whole file:**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { IntervalObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/IntervalObservable';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public counting: boolean;
  public triggerBtnText = 'GO!';
  public subscription: Observable<number>;

  @Input() count = 0;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.counting = false;
  }

  toggleStopwatch(): any {
    if (this.counting === false) {
      this.counting = true;
      this.triggerBtnText = 'STOP';
      this.updateCount()
    } else {
      this.counting = false;
      this.triggerBtnText = 'GO!';
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  updateCount() {
    this.subscription = Observable.interval(1000);
    this.subscription.subscribe(this.counter);
  }

  public counter(value) {
    this.count = value;
    console.log(value);
  }

  resetCount() {
    this.count = 0;
  }

}
```

**here a simple project where it can be tested:** https://bitbucket.org/wtkd/learning-rxjs/branch/moving-to-ng

Comment: Post the exact and complete exception stack trace. But subscription, which you chose to type as any, thus eliminating all the type checks that TypeScript would do for you, is NOT a Subscription. It's an Observable. And there is no unsubscribe method in Observable. Don't use any. Give the appropriate type to your variables, and TypeScript will spot your programming errors for you, at build time. It's the whole point of TypeScript.

Comment: I dont remember exactly but there was something weird with Observable.interval and Angular needing to use `import { IntervalObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/IntervalObservable';`

Comment: @JBNizet stack trace added, ty for the typescript tips, do you know how could I make these observables able to be observed?

Comment: @rjustin ty, I tried your solution but it didn't work

Comment: I'd start by using the recommended imports: `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';` Then decide what you want to store in this.subscription. Either it's an Observable, and you should type it Observable<number>, rename it, and fix the code, or it's a Subscription, and you should type it as Subscription, and fix the code.

Comment: @JBNizet I updated the description with my new code, there is still an issue to unsubscribe (subscribe seems ok now) I just see an error to unsubscribe and I did not understand, could you help?

Comment: Observable has no unsubscribe method. To unsubscribe from an Observable, you call unsubscribe() on the Subscription returned by observable.subscribe().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it so you can subscribe back later but also stop listening on the observable, you can use a different function on observables called [takeWhile](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takewhile.html). You pass a predicate that returns a boolean (`() => { return true || false; }`) to the takeWhile function, and if it returns true then it continues to listen. Your `counting` variable will work wonderfully with this. See the code below for a working example:

Suggested Code:

```
this.subscription
.takeWhile(() => {      // by calling takeWhile and passing in a predicate, 
  return this.counting; // you can have the subscription stop when the counting 
})                      // variable is false.
.subscribe((value) => {
  this.counter = value;
});
```

Also be sure to remove the `.unsubscribe()` call in your `toggleStopwatch()` function!

*Updated to reflect question changes, see revisions for original answer.*